How to get all the EC2 instances that configured by system management using CLI
I want to get all the EC2 instances that configured by system management with Association status: NON_COMPLIANT,
using CLI.
I tried:

aws ssm list-compliance-items 
--resource-types "AWS::SSM::AssociationCompliance" 
--filters Key=ComplianceType,Values=Association 
Key=Status,Values=NON_COMPLIANT 
--query "ComplianceItems[*].[ResourceId, ComplianceType, Status, Details]" 
--output table

and get invalid resource type exception
I want the data that fit to SSM.3
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/ssm-controls.html#ssm-3
Really appreciate your help!
